# Windows : launch .sh using environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, sh

i'm trying on *windows* to launch my server from anywhere in my computer (**start_server.sh**).

Launching my file containing those line manually works fine (using *GitCMD*) (probably not the best, i'm of course open to any advice)

```
cd /c/myservervagrant
echo "Vagrant start";
vagrant up
```

But I'd like to access this file from anywhere, and launch it by simply using something like

> start_server

I'd like to do this to avoid to go back to the root folder of my computer, then go inside a folder, inside a folder, inside a folder and so on...

Edit : forgot to mention, I only have access to my account environment variables, system variables is locked by my company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch an application from within Windows without navigating to the directory you have to [add the directory that contains the application's executable to your Windows path](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).

Or, if you have a script that already launches it, you can of course just add the path of the script.

Link above describes how to edit Windows' system variables. To adjust user-specific variables in Win 10 Pro:

- Click `Win` + `S`
- Type `Edit environment variables for your account`

I don't know whether this method is valid for Home, Edu and other Win 10 versions. Neither can I guarantee this will work in a corporate environments where user's available actions can be severely limited by the corporate IT.

Comment: How to add this inside my account environment variable ? Forgot to mention, I don't have access to my system environment variable (security reason I guess)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: If this resolves your issue, please do accept the answer so it might be useful for other users down the line. If not, please update your question with new info.